# How to parse an xml file and return default value if no element found

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I wrote a simple method in C# to parse a given xml file and return the value of a specific node. It works fine but I'd also like to return a default value if the node is not found instead of throwing an exception. How can I do this? Can the method be written better?
Thanks for any help offered.
John

```
public static string ReadConfigurationFile(string configurationFileName, string root, string section, string name)
{
    try
    {
        String currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        configFilePath = Directory.GetParent(currentDirectory) + configurationFolder + configurationFileName;

        XDocument configXML = XDocument.Load(configFilePath);
        var result = from setting in
                         configXML.Descendants(root)
                            .Descendants(section)
                     select setting.Element(name).Attribute("value").Value;
        return result.First();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Here's a sample of the XML file I parse:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<automationSettings>
    <vmDomain>
        <domainName value = "Domain"/>
        <domainUsername value = "username"/>
        <domainPassword value = "password"/>
    </vmDomain>
</automationSettings>
```

Comment: You can do an explicit cast to `string`, which will return null if the element is not found - `(string)setting.Element(name)`.  You may need to tweak it a bit for your use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start by getting rid of the exception "handling". The node not being found is a "reasonable to expect" error, and one we're going to ensure doesn't result in an exception. Other exceptions - such as the file not being found at all, or not being valid XML - should probably be thrown.

Next, let's stop using a query expression - when you're only using a `select` clause, it doesn't really buy you anything.

As a next step, I'm going to stop assigning to `configFilePath` which is presumably a field. Writing to that field as a side-effect seems like a really bad idea to me. Let's use `Path.Combine` to combine bits of a path as well...

So now we've got:

```
// Work in progress!
public static string ReadConfigurationFile(
    string configurationFileName,
    string root,
    string section,
    string name)
{
    string currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    var fullConfigPath = Path.Combine(
        Directory.GetParent(currentDirectory),
        configurationFolder,
        configurationFileName);

    var configXml = XDocument.Load(fullConfigPath);
    return configXml.Descendants(root)
                    .Descendants(section)
                    .Select(x => x.Element(name).Attribute("value").Value
                    .First();
}
```

That's now going to throw an exception if it can't find either the element or the attribute. We can fix that like this:

```
return configXml.Descendants(root)
                .Descendants(section)
                .Elements(name)
                .Select(x => (string) x.Attribute("value"))
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now, if `Elements()` returns an empty sequence, there'll be nothing to select and `FirstOrDefault()` will return null. If there *is* an element and it doesn't have the `value` attribute, `x.Attribute("value")` will return null, and the explicit conversion from `XAttribute` to `string` will return null.

While we're at it, we're only using `configXml` for one call, so let's inline that, leaving us with:

```
public static string ReadConfigurationFile(
    string configurationFileName,
    string root,
    string section,
    string name)
{
    string currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    var fullConfigPath = Path.Combine(
        Directory.GetParent(currentDirectory),
        configurationFolder,
        configurationFileName);

    return XDocument.Load(fullConfigPath)
                    .Descendants(root)
                    .Descendants(section)
                    .Elements(name)
                    .Select(x => (string) x.Attribute("value"))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Now, that returns `null` rather than the empty string that your original code does. I'd argue that's better, because:

- It allows the caller to differentiate "the setting was provided but empty" from "the setting wasn't provided"
- It allows the caller to use the null-coalescing operator to specify a default value:

  ```
  var setting = ReadConfigurationFile("a", "b", "c", "d") ?? "some default value";
  ```

Comment: Not so much an answer as a full tutorial! Thanks you very much Jon, excellent explanation of a method I never fully understood.

Comment: And this is what makes a simple answer a useful answer, for not just the OP but for future visitors.